# Alternative to scriptPath when migrating GMaven to GMavenPlus

Tags: maven, groovy, gmaven, gmavenplus

I am migrating a legacy Maven build with the [GMaven plugin](https://github.com/groovy/gmaven/tree/master/gmaven-plugin) to [GMavenPlus](https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus) and running into the issue that I don't know how I can call external Groovy classes from a local source folder inside my Groovy script.

Here's my previous setup:

```
<execution>
    <id>process-static-content</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>execute</goal>
    </goals>
    <phase>process-resources</phase>
    <configuration>

        <scriptpath>
            <element>${pom.basedir}/src/main/some-local-path</element>
        </scriptpath>
        <source>
            // call class from scriptpath that needs access
            // to Maven internals
            new SomeClassFromTheAboveFolder(project, log).run();
        </source>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Changing the `<source>` to `<scripts><script>` is obvious, but as far as I can tell, a `<script>` block can only either contain local groovy code or a file path to a script, but neither helps me implement the above usage pattern.

Can anybody provide insight?

Comment: To help, I need to understand your use case. What do you need the scriptPath element for?  The project classes are already on the classpath.

Comment: @Keegan that's exactly what I don't want. I want to use the classes in the build process only, without making them part of the jar

Comment: By "on the classpath" I mean it's on GMavenPlus's classpath.  If you're just wanting the Groovy script to be able to access project classes, that should work out of the box, no scriptPath needed.

Comment: I think I get it now. Let me know if I'm off-track and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you're wanting to add additional Groovy sources to GMavenPlus's classpath because those access classes are not part of the Maven project at the point in the lifecycle where GMavenPlus is invoked (e.g. maybe integratation test classes that you need to access during the *generate-test-sources* phase).

You're correct, there is no mechanism to accomplish this currently (because I simply hadn't considered this scenario).  But I'm happy to add it.  I've opened [#66](https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/issues/66) to add this functionality.